# Uploading files to S3 account from Linux command line

Tags: linux, command-line, upload, amazon-s3

I've got several large files sitting in my Linux hosted account that I need to upload to my S3 account. I don't want to download them first and then upload them into S3.

Is there any way I can "upload" it via the Linux command line? Or can I access it via a website working with Lynx?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

[**S3cmd**](http://s3tools.org/s3cmd) does what you want. Uploading and downloading files, syncing directories and creating buckets.

> S3cmd is a free command line tool and client for uploading, retrieving and managing data in Amazon S3 and other cloud storage service providers that use the S3 protocol, such as Google Cloud Storage or DreamHost DreamObjects. It is best suited for power users who are familiar with command line programs. It is also ideal for batch scripts and automated backup to S3, triggered from cron, etc.

Comment: works like a charm!

Comment: Reference documentation for commands in https://upcloud.com/resources/tutorials/s3cmd-object-storage (Starts from "Configuring S3cmd")

Answer (score 106):

Amazon provides their own CLI tools now too.

From http://aws.amazon.com/cli/

> Using familiar syntax, you can view the contents of your S3 buckets in a directory-based listing.
>
> ```
> $ aws s3 ls s3://mybucket
>       LastWriteTime     Length Name
>       -------------     ------ ----
>                            PRE myfolder/
> 2013-09-03 10:00:00       1234 myfile.txt
> ...
> ```
>
> You can perform recursive uploads and downloads of multiple files in a single folder-level command. The AWS CLI will run these transfers in parallel for increased performance.
>
> ```
> $ aws s3 cp myfolder s3://mybucket/myfolder --recursive
> upload: myfolder/file1.txt to s3://mybucket/myfolder/file1.txt
> upload: myfolder/subfolder/file1.txt to s3://mybucket/myfolder/subfolder/file1.txt
> ...
> ```
>
> A sync command makes it easy to synchronize the contents of a local folder with a copy in an S3 bucket.
>
> ```
> $ aws s3 sync myfolder s3://mybucket/myfolder --exclude *.tmp
> upload: myfolder/newfile.txt to s3://mybucket/myfolder/newfile.txt
> ...
> ```

Documentation for [file related commands is here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/).

Comment: most complete answer! :)

Answer (score 28):

If you can't (perhaps you're on a shared host) or don't want to install extra tools, it is possible to just use bash, curl, and openssl.

http://tmont.com/blargh/2014/1/uploading-to-s3-in-bash

```
file=/path/to/file/to/upload.tar.gz
bucket=your-bucket
resource="/${bucket}/${file}"
contentType="application/x-compressed-tar"
dateValue=`date -R`
stringToSign="PUT\n\n${contentType}\n${dateValue}\n${resource}"
s3Key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
s3Secret=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
signature=`echo -en ${stringToSign} | openssl sha1 -hmac ${s3Secret} -binary | base64`
curl -L -X PUT -T "${file}" \
  -H "Host: ${bucket}.s3.amazonaws.com" \
  -H "Date: ${dateValue}" \
  -H "Content-Type: ${contentType}" \
  -H "Authorization: AWS ${s3Key}:${signature}" \
  https://${bucket}.s3.amazonaws.com/${file}
```

Note that I modified this script from the one in the above link. I added the `-L` option because AWS may insert a redirect in there. The `-L` option will follow the redirect for you.

One other caveat. This won't work for files larger than 5GB. Those require a multi-part upload that would require a more complex script.

Answer (score 13):

A POSIX-compliant shell script that requires openssl, curl and sed only; 
supporting AWS Signature Version 4, which is required for region 
`eu-central-1` (Frankfurt) and recommended for the others:

https://gist.github.com/vszakats/2917d28a951844ab80b1

```
#!/bin/sh -u

# To the extent possible under law, Viktor Szakats (vszakats.net)
# has waived all copyright and related or neighboring rights to this
# script.
# CC0 - https://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/

# Upload a file to Amazon AWS S3 using Signature Version 4
#
# docs:
#    https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-create-canonical-request.html
#
# requires:
#    curl, openssl 1.x, GNU sed, LF EOLs in this file

fileLocal="${1:-example-local-file.ext}"
bucket="${2:-example-bucket}"
region="${3:-}"
storageClass="${4:-STANDARD}"  # or 'REDUCED_REDUNDANCY'

m_openssl() {
  if [ -f /usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/bin/openssl ]; then
    /usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/bin/openssl "$@"
  elif [ -f /usr/local/opt/openssl/bin/openssl ]; then
    /usr/local/opt/openssl/bin/openssl "$@"
  else
    openssl "$@"
  fi
}

m_sed() {
  if which gsed > /dev/null 2>&1; then
    gsed "$@"
  else
    sed "$@"
  fi
}

awsStringSign4() {
  kSecret="AWS4$1"
  kDate=$(printf         '%s' "$2" | m_openssl dgst -sha256 -hex -mac HMAC -macopt "key:${kSecret}"     2>/dev/null | m_sed 's/^.* //')
  kRegion=$(printf       '%s' "$3" | m_openssl dgst -sha256 -hex -mac HMAC -macopt "hexkey:${kDate}"    2>/dev/null | m_sed 's/^.* //')
  kService=$(printf      '%s' "$4" | m_openssl dgst -sha256 -hex -mac HMAC -macopt "hexkey:${kRegion}"  2>/dev/null | m_sed 's/^.* //')
  kSigning=$(printf 'aws4_request' | m_openssl dgst -sha256 -hex -mac HMAC -macopt "hexkey:${kService}" 2>/dev/null | m_sed 's/^.* //')
  signedString=$(printf  '%s' "$5" | m_openssl dgst -sha256 -hex -mac HMAC -macopt "hexkey:${kSigning}" 2>/dev/null | m_sed 's/^.* //')
  printf '%s' "${signedString}"
}

iniGet() {
  # based on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22550265/read-certain-key-from-certain-section-of-ini-file-sed-awk#comment34321563_22550640
  printf '%s' "$(m_sed -n -E "/\[$2\]/,/\[.*\]/{/$3/s/(.*)=[ \\t]*(.*)/\2/p}" "$1")"
}

# Initialize access keys

if [ -z "${AWS_CONFIG_FILE:-}" ]; then
  if [ -z "${AWS_ACCESS_KEY:-}" ]; then
    echo 'AWS_CONFIG_FILE or AWS_ACCESS_KEY/AWS_SECRET_KEY envvars not set.'
    exit 1
  else
    awsAccess="${AWS_ACCESS_KEY}"
    awsSecret="${AWS_SECRET_KEY}"
    awsRegion='us-east-1'
  fi
else
  awsProfile='default'

  # Read standard aws-cli configuration file
  # pointed to by the envvar AWS_CONFIG_FILE
  awsAccess="$(iniGet "${AWS_CONFIG_FILE}" "${awsProfile}" 'aws_access_key_id')"
  awsSecret="$(iniGet "${AWS_CONFIG_FILE}" "${awsProfile}" 'aws_secret_access_key')"
  awsRegion="$(iniGet "${AWS_CONFIG_FILE}" "${awsProfile}" 'region')"
fi

# Initialize defaults

fileRemote="${fileLocal}"

if [ -z "${region}" ]; then
  region="${awsRegion}"
fi

echo "Uploading" "${fileLocal}" "->" "${bucket}" "${region}" "${storageClass}"
echo "| $(uname) | $(m_openssl version) | $(m_sed --version | head -1) |"

# Initialize helper variables

httpReq='PUT'
authType='AWS4-HMAC-SHA256'
service='s3'
baseUrl=".${service}.amazonaws.com"
dateValueS=$(date -u +'%Y%m%d')
dateValueL=$(date -u +'%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ')
if hash file 2>/dev/null; then
  contentType="$(file -b --mime-type "${fileLocal}")"
else
  contentType='application/octet-stream'
fi

# 0. Hash the file to be uploaded

if [ -f "${fileLocal}" ]; then
  payloadHash=$(m_openssl dgst -sha256 -hex < "${fileLocal}" 2>/dev/null | m_sed 's/^.* //')
else
  echo "File not found: '${fileLocal}'"
  exit 1
fi

# 1. Create canonical request

# NOTE: order significant in ${headerList} and ${canonicalRequest}

headerList='content-type;host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date;x-amz-server-side-encryption;x-amz-storage-class'

canonicalRequest="\
${httpReq}
/${fileRemote}

content-type:${contentType}
host:${bucket}${baseUrl}
x-amz-content-sha256:${payloadHash}
x-amz-date:${dateValueL}
x-amz-server-side-encryption:AES256
x-amz-storage-class:${storageClass}

${headerList}
${payloadHash}"

# Hash it

canonicalRequestHash=$(printf '%s' "${canonicalRequest}" | m_openssl dgst -sha256 -hex 2>/dev/null | m_sed 's/^.* //')

# 2. Create string to sign

stringToSign="\
${authType}
${dateValueL}
${dateValueS}/${region}/${service}/aws4_request
${canonicalRequestHash}"

# 3. Sign the string

signature=$(awsStringSign4 "${awsSecret}" "${dateValueS}" "${region}" "${service}" "${stringToSign}")

# Upload

curl -s -L --proto-redir =https -X "${httpReq}" -T "${fileLocal}" \
  -H "Content-Type: ${contentType}" \
  -H "Host: ${bucket}${baseUrl}" \
  -H "X-Amz-Content-SHA256: ${payloadHash}" \
  -H "X-Amz-Date: ${dateValueL}" \
  -H "X-Amz-Server-Side-Encryption: AES256" \
  -H "X-Amz-Storage-Class: ${storageClass}" \
  -H "Authorization: ${authType} Credential=${awsAccess}/${dateValueS}/${region}/${service}/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=${headerList}, Signature=${signature}" \
  "https://${bucket}${baseUrl}/${fileRemote}"
```

Notice, the script will enable server-side

AES256 encryption by default.

Comment: For the search engines: This is the correct solution for eu-central-1 and in general if you get the error `The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256`

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively you can try https://github.com/minio/mc

`mc` provides minimal tools to work with Amazon S3 compatible cloud storage and filesystems. It has features like resumable uploads, progress bar, parallel copy. `mc` is written in Golang and released under Apache license v2.

[Reference](https://min.io/docs/minio/linux/reference/minio-mc.html) for configuration(setup) & commands

Comment: This is a great answer. I don't necessarily want to do it in bash, as the other (good) answers are suggesting. I just don't want to install all the dependencies that awscli requires.

Answer (score 1):

I've found Python's AWS bindings in the `boto` package (`pip install boto`) to be helpful for uploading data to S3.

The following script can be called like: `python script_name.py "sub_bucket_name" "*.zip"` where `sub_bucket_name` indicates the name of the directory in which the files should be stored in S3, and `*.zip` is a glob path designating one or more files to be uploaded:

```
import sys, glob, os, boto
from boto.s3.key import Key

def percent_cb(complete, total):
    sys.stdout.write('.')
    sys.stdout.flush()

id = '< your id here >'               # AWS Access Key ID
secret = '< your secret here >'       # AWS Secret Access Key
bucket_name = '< your bucket here >'  # Bucket wherein content will be stored
conn = boto.connect_s3(id, secret)    # Establish a connection to S3
bucket = conn.get_bucket(bucket_name, validate=False)  # Connect to bucket
k  = Key(bucket)                      # Connect to the bucket's key

for i in glob.glob(sys.argv[2]):      # Read in files to push to S3

        sub_bucket = sys.argv[1]  # Directory within bucket where files will be stored
        k.key = sub_bucket + "/" + os.path.basename(i) # Path each uploaded file will have on S3

        k.set_contents_from_filename(i, cb=percent_cb, num_cb=10)  # Push data to S3

        print 'Uploading %s to Amazon S3 bucket %s' % (i, bucket_name)  # Report status
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the command:

```
aws s3 sync /path/to/the/folder/ s3://bucket name
```

This will automatically upload your folder to the created s3 bucket.