# How upload files larger than 5GB to Amazon S3 in Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I need to send some `SQL Server` files from my `Windows Server 2008` to Amazon S3.
After doing some researches I found some programs that do that, but it (the **freewares**) **can't** :

- send files larger  than 5GB
- schedule task to send files automatically

Of course there's some programs that do that, but they're very expensive, because today I have more than 30 servers to do that.

Any ideia how send these files to Amazon S3 in a free way ?

Thank you

Comment: Related question: https://superuser.com/questions/279986/uploading-files-to-s3-account-from-linux-command-line

Answer (score 1):

You can try [minio client](http://minio.io/#mc) aka mc. It is available for Windows.

"mc cp" command can do the needful. It will handle the multipart upload for you.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

http://s3.codeplex.com/

Have a look at this, I believe this is a suitable way to do this.

As for the schedule, you can set this up as a scheduled task in windows using the correct parameters for it.

Look at the documentation for a list of all parameters.

Comment: Great tool Ash, but I found one problem with it, I can't send files bigger than 5GB with the '/sync' option, so I can't send to Amazon the files that wasn't send before bigger than 5GB and it sub-folders.

Answer (score 0):

5GB is the size limit set by AWS for any single object being uploaded:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadingObjects.html

Consider using the multi-part uploader:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/uploadobjusingmpu.html

Comment: That is incorrect, 5 TB is the limit. Google it

Comment: Please correct your answer: a single object can be up to 5TB. The 5G limit refers to a _single PUT_